# Java regex to match integer

Tags: java, regex

I know that java short-circuits its boolean evaluations. 
So if (false && true) wouldn't reach the true condition since java already knows the first is false.

I'm having a problem though. I have to check if the input is a positive integer and is lesser than another integer.

The condition looks like this:

```
    if (inputIsPositiveInteger(input) && inputIsLessThanSomeNumber(input,someNumber)) {
      doSomething();
    }

    boolean inputIsPositiveInteger(String input) {
      String regex = "[0-9]*";
      return input.matches(regex);
    }

    boolean inputIsLessThanSomeNumber(String input, String someNumber) {
      return (Integer.parseInt(input) < Integer.parseInt(someNumber));
    }
```

This throws a NumberFormatException if my input isn't an integer since I'm parsing the input to an Integer in the second condition. I thought if the first condition was false it would just exit the if statement.

Can anyone shed light on this?

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.akolopez.servlets.ProductServlet.inputIsLessThanStock(ProductServlet.java:94)
    at com.akolopez.servlets.ProductServlet.validateInput(ProductServlet.java:78)
    at com.akolopez.servlets.ProductServlet.doPost(ProductServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Edit: updated my post with the other methods.
Edit2: I added a stack trace if it helps.

Comment: Can we see both of the methods too? And yes, you are correct, the `if-statement` will only run `doSomething()` if both methods return `true`. Which leads me to believe that the error is being thrown while running one of the methods.

Comment: I edited my original post with the two methods.

Comment: Your `inputIsPositiveInteger` will also accept empty string `""` which can later cause `NumberFormatException`. Consider using `+` instead of `*`. Also can you post more details about thrown exception? Stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps [0-9]+ would be a better regex since it forces the input to have at least one digit, while [0-9]* is satisfied by an empty string.

Comment: Oh. Right, but I'm still getting errors with random letters anyway. I don't understand why the short circuit evaluation isn't working.

Comment: It's a NumberFormatException on the second method condition since it says that I'm parsing something that isn't an integer.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. Please post short but full code which I could copy-paste to get similar Exception. Otherwise it would be just guessing. Also from my experience people tend to solve their problems on their own while creating such minimal example.

Comment: I've found out what is wrong. The first method condition is returning true even for letters. I guess my regex is incorrect? I need to check that the input matches only numbers.

Comment: Could the problem be with your second parameter: String someNumber?

Comment: Your `inputIsPositiveInteger` works fine for me. Only improvement I see here is shortening code with `return input.matches("[0-9]+");` but this will work exactly the same as your current code. Like I said before post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with my regex. It needed to be "[^0-9]". I don't know what the ^ is for though. I also can't find it in any of the regex specifications.

Comment: `^` inside `[..]` will reverse accepted content. So `[^0-9]` will represent anything which is NOT digit. It is the same as `\\D`. Considering that it works for you I assume that you are using your method with some kind of negation before like `!isPositive()` which is not what you posted in your question.

Comment: Turns out it's to signify the beginning of the line. I still don't understand why I need it though.

Comment: It means 'not' when inside the [] as you had it, and beginning of line otherwise. It isn't what you need. You need "^[0-9]+$", so that the entire string must match. And the problem had nothing to do with short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @EJP surrounding regex with `^` `$` is not required if OP is using `matches` method. It will return true only if entire string will match regex.

Comment: Oh. I'm not negating the method. I'm going to have to study my code to find out where the negation is happening. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Are you sure `someNumber` (which you don't validate) is not what is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Validate both arguments, `input` and `someNumber`:

```
void whatever(String input, String someNumber) {
    if (inputIsLessThanSomeNumber(input, someNumber)) {
        doSomething();
    }
}

boolean inputIsLessThanSomeNumber(String input, String someNumber) {
    if (inputIsPositiveInteger(input) && inputIsPositiveInteger(someNumber))
    {
        return (Integer.parseInt(input) < Integer.parseInt(someNumber));
    }

    return false;
}

boolean inputIsPositiveInteger(String input) {
    String regex = "[0-9]+";
    return input.matches(regex);
}
```

Comment: I agree with this. The OP seems to not be checking the other number. Also `+` instead of `*` is a good suggestion. `[0-9]*` matches an empty String.

Comment: I +1 it as nice improvement but OP claims that reversing accepted characters by regex solves his problem so I am afraid it is not entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not certain your input is going to be in the correct format, you need to catch that exception.  For instance, you could do the following:

```
try {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(input);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(someNumber);
    if(x>0 && x<y) {
        doSomething();
    }
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // One of the inputs is not a number.
}
```

It also seems to make sense to do this way because you care about the inputs as integers, so convert them to integers and then do your comparisons.

Comment: Using `catch` as part of logic is not best way to code and OP is clearly trying to avoid it by validating his input before using it in method which could throw Exception.

Comment: I disagree.  In cases where you have no control over the situation (whether or not a string is in the proper format), exception handling is perfectly fine.  In fact, compare the code above and it seems pretty clear that using exception handling is not only shorter, but is easier to understand.

Comment: OPs code can be rewritten in many ways which will be even more readable then handling exceptions. Other point is term of speed. Reusing compiled regex patterns is faster then creating and handling exceptions.